# Discord.py | Change max_concurrency mid-command execution

Tags: python, discord

I take multiple inputs from bots users, and I want to disable their use of commands while the inputs are being taken.

```
def check(m):
  return m.channel == channel and ctx.message.author == m.author

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
  await ctx.send("How are you today?")
  try:
    response = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30, check=check) # I want to ensure users cannot execute a command during this stage of the command.
    await ctx.send(f"Glad to see you're feeling {response.content}!")
  except:
    await ctx.send("You must be depressed! I didn't hear a word... :(")
```

I have noticed max_concurrency exists, and I feel it could be applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate the command as follows:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.max_concurrency(1, commands.BucketType.member, wait=False)
async def hello(ctx):
```

This will cause the command to only permit one invocation per guild member at any given time. Reference [BucketType](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.BucketType) and [MaxConcurrency](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.max_concurrency) in the docs for detailed explanations of their implementations.